# pass two selectors into .parents() method

Tags: jquery

There are two containers 'cont1' and 'cont2'. Within each there is one html element that can be clicked. I want to know under which container the element is clicked so want to check whether a clicked element has parent 'cont1' or 'cont2' and which one. I tried to pass these both containers identifiers into the jQuery selector but it didn't return elements:

```
$(html_elem).click(function(e) { 
    var parent = $(e.currentTarget).parents('#cont1', '#cont2'); //parent is undefined
});
```

However, when I test whether one particular parent is there, it works

```
$(html_elem).click(function(e) { 
    var parent = $(e.currentTarget).parents('#cont1'); //parent is found
});
```

Am I right to assume that .parents() method doesn't work with multiple selectors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use one string, with the comma contained within.

```
var parent = $(e.currentTarget).parents('#cont1, #cont2');
```